# Sync sharepoint online lists

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, document-library, sharepoint-online

I am trying to syncronize two Document librarys, using a workflow and im kinda stuck. My main issue is that the source library contains document sets. Copying the documents is fairly easy using a workflow, my problem is copying the folder structure. I am mostly just looking for a pointer in the right direction, pehaps another approaches than a workflow. Is there pehaps a way using a workflow to copy list-items? As far as i can tell i can only copy documents :/

PS. It's SharePoint online.